# Are there sets with all sequences convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

Let S be a nonempty subset of the real numbers.
Let every sequence in S be convergent.
Can this only happen for sets with less than 2 points?
How would you prove this?

Comment: Hint: $S$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: It really depends on how you define convergence. There is a notion of topological convergence (a point is a limit point if any open set containing it contains all but finitely many elements of the sequence) and there is also a notion of convergence which is more analytic in nature (that of $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large).

Comment: @Clayton Yes, but taking $S$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R$, these two notions of convergence are the same.

Comment: @TomCruise: I try not to presuppose a topology on a given set. Just because it is a subset of $\Bbb R$ does not mean $\Bbb R$ should have the standard topology.

Comment: @Jessica: If you let $\Bbb R$ have the indiscrete topology, then every sequence of any subset is convergent (although convergence is not well defined in this case).

Comment: @Clayton I think the fact that it is tagged Real Analysis and not Topology means it is safe to assume that $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology on it

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your set has at least two points $x,y$. Consider the sequence $a_{2n}=x$ and $a_{2n+1}=y$. For this sequence to be convergent, we must have $x=y$- contadiction.